# how to print an alternating zigzag-ish number pattern

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to pseudo code this for an hour and tried multiple things but i cant figure this out at all. how do i print this shape when the user inputs a number, like 10?

```
   1
2     3
   4  
5     6 
   7     
8     9
   10
```

Comment: Instead of pseudo-code, try some real code, then you'll be able to tell for sure if it's working or not, and include what you've tried in your question.

Comment: it is clearly based on the factor of 3.

Comment: show what you have tried, this isn't a coding service

Answer (score 0):

Might look better with a true type font, but here's the pattern...

```js
var theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
var oneNotTwo = true;
theDiv.innerHTML = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (oneNotTwo) {
    theDiv.innerHTML += '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>';
  } else {
    theDiv.innerHTML += i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (i + 1) + '<br/>';
    i++;
  }
  oneNotTwo = !oneNotTwo;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<script>
    var num = 10; 
    var flag = 0; 
    for(var i = 1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            document.write("&nbsp;" + i + "&nbsp;<br>"); 
            flag = 1; 
        }
        else 
        {
            document.write(i + "&nbsp;" + ++i + "<br>");        
            flag = 0; 

        }
    }
</script>
```

The flag is used to determine whether to print one or two numbers on the current line. You have to make sure not to jump over the limit when printing two numbers, though. I have not included that check.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str="";
var one=true;
for(var i=1;i<=10;i=i+1){
  if(one){
    str +="&emsp;"+i+"&emsp;"+"<br>";
  
    }else{
      str +=i+"&emsp;&emsp;"+(i+1)+"<br>";
        i=i+1;//extra increment when two numbers are added
      }
  one=!one;
  }

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=str;
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```
var num     = 10;
var zigzag  = [];
var odd     = true; // odd row, even row

for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (odd) {
        zigzag.push(i);
    } else {
        zigzag.push([i, i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    odd = !odd;
}
/* loop through the zigzag array and print it however you like
zigzag = [
    [1],
    [2, 3],
    [4],
    [5, 6],
    [7],
    [8, 9],
    [10],
];
*/
```

Since I liked your question because it's challenging, I took it one step further. You can set min and max values for the columns:

```
var num     = 25;
var zigzag  = [];
var odd     = true;
var min     = 3;
var max     = 5;

for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (odd) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < min; j++) {
            var val = i + j;
            if (val <= num) {
                row.push(val);
            }
        }
        if (row.length > 0) {
            zigzag.push(row);
        }
        i += min - 1;
    } else {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            var val = i + j;
            if (val <= num) {
                row.push(val);
            }
        }
        if (row.length > 0) {
            zigzag.push(row);
        }
        i += max - 1;
    }
    odd = !odd;
}
/*
zigzag = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11],
    [12,13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19],
    [20,21,22,23,24],
    [25]
]
*/
```

And if there's a remaining number, such as 25 in the example above, there'll be a new row for it.